# What is the meaning of the open record pattern?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, record

OCaml has an explicit syntactic construct (See [`Parsetree.pattern_desc`, constructor `Ppat_record`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/parsing/parsetree.mli#L198)) to discriminate between "open" and "closed" record patterns.

This seems to have no influence whatsoever on the pattern matching:

```
utop # type r = {repr:int; foo:int} ;;
type r = { repr : int; foo : int; } 
utop # let f = function {repr} -> repr;;
val f : r -> int =  <fun> 
utop # let g = function {repr;_} -> repr;;
val g : r -> int = <fun>
```

So what is/was its purpose? Is this some kind of SML relic?

Answer (score 2):

It is just a language extension to tell the compiler that you ignored some fields on purpose so that you can have a warning when you forget a field.

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec226